# Why async component doesn't change when the route update?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State) in [my code on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ysyx2) (seen below). When I click on `goto product-2` after `goto product-1`, nothing happens. I expected the `<product-item>` component to change based on the clicked component, but only the URL changes. I even have a `beforeRouteUpdate` hook function. How do I fix this?

```js
// main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ProductPage from './product-page.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const routes = [
  { path: '/:productId', component: ProductPage },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

new Vue({
  router,  
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/product-1">goto product1</router-link>
    <br>
    <br>
    <router-link to="/product-2">goto product2</router-link>

    <div>Router view:</div>
    <router-view :key="$route.params.productId"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
// product-page.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <product-item></product-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "product-page",
  components: {
    ProductItem: () => ({
      component: import("./product-item.vue"),
      loading: { template: "<div>loading....</div>" }
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    product item: {{product}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ProductItem",
  mounted: function () {
    this.product = this.$route.params.productId;
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate: function(to, from, next) {
    this.product = to.params.productId;
    next();
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      product: null
    }
  },
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the *route path* (i.e., `/:productId`) does not actually change between the links for `/product-1` and `/product-2` (even though the parameter values do), so `router-view` does not re-render.

The workaround is to `key` the `router-view` based on the `productId` parameter:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.params.productId" />
```

[image: Edit Refreshing router-view on parameter change]